# REQUIRED_SYNCHRONIZED_SECONDARIES_TO_COMMIT for Readscale AG failover

Tags: availability-groups, sql-server-2017, high-availability

I have 2 node  Readscale AG setup where each node is on a different data center. I want to know if  SET (REQUIRED_SYNCHRONIZED_SECONDARIES_TO_COMMIT = 1); needs to be run even after setting both the replicas to Synchronous mode.

Also, Application services were shutdown before fail-over took place, so this is where my ambiguity lies. I used the following Microsoft documentation for the process..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-read-scale-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017